# Giving error when i adding string to child node

Tags: java, swing, jtree

```
public void createNode(int group){
     DefaultMutableTreeNode root = null;
     DefaultMutableTreeNode child[] = null;
     List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

     ExpressionBuilder builder=new ExpressionBuilder();
     list = builder.getExpression(group,0);
     root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(groupString);    
     defaultTreeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);

     for(int i=0; i<list.size();i++){
         child[i] = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(list.get(i));
         defaultTreeModel.insertNodeInto(child[i], root, i);
     }
 }
```

when i am making child array it is giving me error of null pointer exception. list is populated correctly.

Comment: Could you please explain what's that ExpressionBuilder Object??

Comment: ExpressionBuilder is a class that fetches me data from the database. The getExpression(group,0) return me list of expression that are present in the db. when printing list it is populated correctly. child[i] = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(list.get(i).toString()); but this line is throwing me error when i am trying to add string node to child

Comment: root.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(list.get(i).toString())); this is working.   :)

Comment: Yes, but @camickr's response is the solution for your problem :), I oversaw this :P

Answer (score 1):

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode child[] = null;
```

The child array is null.

When you create an array you need to do something like:

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode child[] = new DefaultMutableTreeNode[???];
```

So you would need to create the array after you create the List so you know what size to make the array.